# Two websites (and domains) on one hosting

Tags: web-hosting, php, godaddy, vps

So I am a poor college student, thus I can't afford dedicated hosting, cloud or anything fancy of the like...

However I managed to purchase myself two domain names say `http://abc.com` and `http://def.com` for two completely different PHP applications (both are CakePHP, database-driven applications). I also have an Economy hosting package from GoDaddy.

So, my question is: will I be able to host those two applications on the same host? Is it just as simple as creating two separate folders 'abc' and 'def' and have the domain names point to them?

I have found something of similar nature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809112/hosting-two-domains-using-only-one-vps . Not sure if this will apply to my case using GoDaddy service.

Thanks for your help guys. I have never actually done deployment before. My whole life has been around LAMP stack local development. Hopefully this will clear up my mind a little.

Comment: belongs on serverfault

Comment: Should be migrated, definitely

Comment: How do you suggest migration?

Comment: @tekknolagi you have to have permission to vote to close.

Comment: @Daniel Ah. Gotcha. the "flag" privilege or is it something different?

Comment: YAY just said it should be migrated :)

Comment: @tekknolagi - you can flag.

Answer (score 2):

No, not on the GoDaddy Economy plan.
If you can take the jump to $7.99/mo instead, then you can go nuts with the domains.
Go to [their hosting plans page](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=9009), "Features" tab, "Domains" header(blue-ish color), "Multiple Web Sites"

[A Small Orange](http://www.asmallorange.com/hosting/shared/) have a "Tiny" plan at $25/**year** (since you're broke) that will support multiple domains, but even their more-regular Small plan is still a bit less than GoDaddy, along with multi-domains.

You might also ask yourself if you *really* need entirely separate domains for the apps. Your current Economy plan does allow you up to 25 sub-domains.

Answer (score 1):

Generic answer: Yes, what you want is called [`Name-based Virtual Hosting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based).

Does GoDaddy support it? No idea.

Comment: I dislike answering and then liking someone else's answer more :P

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. I use Webfaction for this, and have at least 8 domains on one account. It's wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy both application to your GoDaddy host and use HTML's `iframe` to load the one or the other through the two different names.

Comment: People still use iFrames...?! o.O

Comment: Hm, no. I didn't claim this to be a good solution ;-)

Comment: ^^Like^^ (What is this...facebook??)